# If $p,q$ are polynomials and $q$ divides $p$ in the space of holomorphic functions, then the quotient is a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{C}^{m}$. $p,q$ are two polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[z_{1},\ldots,z_{m}]$ and $q$ divides $p$ in $\mathcal{O}(\Omega)$. Then $p=fq$, for some $f\in\mathcal{O}(\Omega)$. If we assume that $Z(q)\cap\Omega$ is non-empty, then is it true that $f$ is a polynomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

For example, take $m=1$, $\Omega=\mathbb{D}$, $q=z(z+2)$ and $p=z$.  Then $Z(q)\cap\Omega=\{0\}$, $f=\frac1{z+2}$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$ but not a polynomial.

Comment: Right. Thanks for this. On this note, what if I assume furthermore that $q$ is irreducible or more generally, zero sets of all irreducible components of $q$ intersect $\Omega$?

Comment: Yes.  If $q$ is irreducible, then $f$ is a polynomial. Since $q$ is irreducible and $\dim Z(q)\cap\Omega=\dim Z(q)$, the Zariski closure of $Z(q)\cap\Omega$ is $Z(q)$.  Then $p=0$ on $Z(q)\cap\Omega$, hence on $Z(q)$, and $(q)=I(Z(q))$ gives $q\mid p$ in the polynomial ring.

Comment: Thanks again. This was really helpful.